# Alway failed ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission without asking for permission

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use setMyLocationEnabled(true). But unable to use it due to permission issue.

My android application doesn't ask for permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. Without asking for permission it is always failed to get permission.

Android Version of Testing Device: 6.0.1
Compile SDK Version and Target SDK:  API-25, Android 7.1.1
Build Tool Version: 25.0.3
Min SDK Version: API-22, Android 5.1

Following permissions are added in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="edu.bloomu.huskies.tsc71523.skatelogger.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

MapsActivity.java:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(0, 0);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("TestLocation"));

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION-------Successful");
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        Log.e("LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION-------Failed");
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("LOCATION", "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION-------Successful");
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        Log.e("LOCATION", "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION-------Failed");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: you maybe checked the "don't ask again" flag in the request permission dialog, try clear data.
And you are not requesting the permission

Comment: It worked after installing "Google Play services". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android Marshmallow (6.0) you have to use the new permissions model (ask for permission) if your target is API level 23 or greater.

This talk will help you understand the new model: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A

This helper library can also make it easier to use and support older versions of Android seamlessly: https://github.com/hiqes/andele